# Is there any midnight commander alternative that allows me to see the folder size?

Tags: server, software-recommendation, directory, vps, file-size

I want any alternative for Ubuntu 11.04 that runs on the command window that allows me to see which folder use up a lot of space.

P.S. It's for my VPS.

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you looked at the results of `apt-cache search midnight` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Midnight Commander go to menu `Command` and select `Show directory sizes`.

Keyboard shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

Try using `tree`

```
sudo apt-get install tree
```

Then run `tree /mainfolder/folder1 -d`

```
host@hostname:~$ tree /etc/apt -d -h   ( -d shows only directory ) 
/etc/apt
├── [4.0K]  apt.conf.d   <------ where 4k is size of directory 
├── [4.0K]  preferences.d
├── [4.0K]  sources.list.d
└── [4.0K]  trusted.gpg.d
```

You can further refer here at [Tree manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man1/tree.1.html) for preferred Usage.

Answer (score 3):

There is a program called ranger that allows you to do this. Download and install ranger.
`sudo apt-get install ranger`

Then, run `ranger :set display_size_in_main_column true`. That will make it display the file size in the main column whenever `ranger` is run. You can navigate through the columns with your arrow keys. See `man ranger` for more details.

You can download and install it from the [site](http://ranger.nongnu.org/download.html);  instructions are there as well.

Comment: Ranger is not available for natty

Comment: @HackToHell Download it from the ranger homepage. http://ranger.nongnu.org/download.html

Comment: Ranger is nice...